# Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: mysql

I'v tried a few statements including joins, but have not been able to insert data from three other MySQL tables into one. On my last attempt, I received this error: Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
Please see below for the query I entered.
(I'm new to coding, so I'm still pretty much a novice with MySQL. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.)

```
INSERT INTO cases (person_id, last_name, first_name, date_applied) 
SELECT person_id, last_name, first_name, 
date_applied FROM person  UNION SELECT (program_name) FROM program 
UNION SELECT (status) FROM casestatus
```

Comment: Can you share your table structures please?

Comment: There are 4 tables: cases, case status, person, program. The 'cases' table has foreign keys for the three other tables. The 'cases' table has the following columns: case no. (automatically generated), date_applied, year, client_name, and status. The 'person' table has the following columns: person_id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, gender, and ssn. The 'program' table's column is program_name. The 'case status' table has a column called status.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, I edited the statement and was able to insert the data into the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SELECT statement before the `UNION` keyword selects 4 columns but the SELECT statement after the `UNION` keyword selects only 1 column. You cannot build a `UNION` with different number of columns, thats the reason you get this error message about "different number of columns".